# Parse/split URLs in a pandas dataframe using urllib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, urllib

I'm trying to split URLs and put the fragments in a dataframe. I found this thread [pythonic way to parse/split URLs in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885589/pythonic-way-to-parse-split-urls-in-a-pandas-dataframe) and try to apply it, but for some reason it gives me an error.

I am under Python 3.x so I used the following:

```
import pandas
import urllib

urls = ['https://www.google.com/something','https://mail.google.com/anohtersomething', 'https://www.amazon.com/yetanotherthing']
df['protocol'],df['domain'],df['path'],df['query'],df['fragment'] = zip(*df['url'].map(urllib.parse.urlsplit))
```

I get an error saying `KeyError: 'urls'`, not sure what it means.

If someone could help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you used assumes that the links are in a dataframe. Here's the correct solution:

```
import urllib
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
urls = ['https://www.google.com/something','https://mail.google.com/anohtersomething', 'https://www.amazon.com/yetanotherthing']
df['protocol'],df['domain'],df['path'],df['query'],df['fragment'] = zip(*[urllib.parse.urlsplit(x) for x in urls])
```

**Result**

```
  protocol           domain               path query fragment
0    https   www.google.com         /something
1    https  mail.google.com  /anohtersomething
2    https   www.amazon.com   /yetanotherthing
```